# Negative segment index?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

Is it possible to access a segment register with a negative index? 
If yes, what would be the result? Does this even make sense?

```
mov   rcx, cs:off_619528   ; 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD0 -> -48

mov   rdx, fs:[rcx]
```

Comment: BTW,  you don't need to load 64bit constants; there is a `mov r64, imm64`.  AT&T syntax uses `movabs` for it, while NASM/YASM use it automatically instead of truncating constants, when they don't fit into 32bit-sign-extended `mov r64, imm32`.  (Some assemblers may also assemble to a zero-extended `mov r32, imm32`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently in 64 bit mode the cpu is really lazy and simply adds the segment base to the given offset. As such, negative values are valid and do what one would expect, that is address before the segment base. The address still needs to be valid, though.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <asm/prctl.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char* addr;
    unsigned char val;
    arch_prctl(ARCH_GET_FS, &addr);
    printf("FS base: %p\nold value: 0x%02x\n", addr, addr[-48]);
    addr[-48] = 0x42;
    printf("new value: 0x%02x\n", addr[-48]);
    __asm__ __volatile__ ( "movb %%fs:(%1), %0" : "=r" (val) : "r" (-48LL));
    printf("read using fs: 0x%02x\n", val);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

> ```
> $ ./a.out
> FS base: 0x7ff053c03700
> old value: 0x00
> new value: 0x42
> read using fs: 0x42
> ```

PS: Sorry, I got this wrong the first time around.